# Display a running date and time in a textbox in C#

Tags: c#

I've try searching in this website ways to display date and time. But all the example here shows only static date and time. Is there a way to display date and time which is running or I should say increment every second? Does it involve updating the time every second?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use a [timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) object and in the [tick](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.tick(v=vs.110).aspx) event show the date in the textbox
in winforms use

```
System.Windows.Forms.Timer tmr = null;
private void StartTimer()
{
    tmr = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    tmr.Interval = 1000;
    tmr.Tick += new EventHandler(tmr_Tick);
    tmr.Enabled = true;
}

void tmr_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myTextBox.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

Comment: I don't think the DateTime can be directly assigned to the `TextBox`, `myTextBox.Text = DateTime.Now;` is doomed to fail

Comment: I've tried your code but there's this error: 'Timer' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.Windows.Forms.Timer' and 'System.Threading.Timer'". How to solve this?

Comment: if you are using your own thread for example a background worker then you would have to invoke the myTextBox.Text before you can set any value

Comment: Did you call the method StartTimer() on form load for example

Comment: How do we call StartTimer() on form load?

Comment: Another thing, now the date is showing like this MM/dd/yyyy. How do I change it to show dd/MM/yyyy?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx) to your form.  Set it to fire once per second.  In the event handler for your timer, update the text box with the current time.

Answer (score 1):

You're right in your second option.

It's all about using a timer and update *TextBox* with current time.

Answer (score 0):

Use a timer with an interval of 1 second. If your app is winforms, use timer from windows.forms namespace http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx , it runs in the same thread as gui, so it is safe to update gui. You also can use timer from system.threading namespace, but in this case you should update controls in thread-safe manner by calling invoke method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728.aspx. If your app is web, use javascript instead

Comment: No it's not a web app. It's just a C# .net program.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Delay method in Task, which takes milliseconds as an input. For me the code for the Time update is like as below,

```
Using System.Threading.Tasks;    
async void TimeUpdater()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            TxtTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }
    }
```

This will update the UI and wait for `1 Second` and then again iterate over, for infinite times. Also don`t forget to make the method `async`, because of the `await operator`. As I`ve researched this is the easiest method to get a running date and time in the UI weather WinForms or WPF.